# Exporting .xlsx and .pdf where filename already exists

Tags: excel, vba

I need some basic help that I can't get right in my code.

Saving as both an .xlsx and PDF file, in the same location, just can't get it to prompt if filename already exists

```
Sub SaveAs()
Dim Path As String
Dim filename As String
Path = "C:\Users\yard\Dropbox\Modus\Purchase Orders\"
filename = Range("E4")
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Path & filename & ".xls", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=Path & filename & ".pdf", Quality:= _
        xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Or have I cancelled that out by using Application.DisplayAlerts = False?

I don't want to be prompted regarding a macro enabled workbook when saving the excel file, however I would like it to prompt if the filename already exists.

Comment: Bone … If this code is not used in an Excel Add-In there is a high probability that you meant to use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`. Note that `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook this code is running at while `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook that has the focus (is on top). While `ThisWorkbook` is very reliable  `ActiveWorkbook` can easily change by a click of a user. So be careful you don't mix them up.

Comment: Ah well there you go, as you can probably tell I've just pieced this together from some googling (this page in particular) and recording my own macros. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the lines with If Conditions added in the Code:

```
Dim Path As String
Dim filename As String

Path = "C:\Users\yard\Dropbox\Modus\Purchase Orders\"

filename = Range("E4")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    If Not Len(dir(Path & filename & ".xls")) = 0 Then MsgBox "Xls File Already Exist"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Path & filename & ".xls", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

    If Not Len(dir(Path & filename & ".pdf")) = 0 Then MsgBox "PDF File Already Exist"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=Path & filename & ".pdf", Quality:= _
        xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

You can use `Dir` to check if the File Exists

Comment: Thank you so very much !